# Share NuGet feed

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

We are using the NuGet workflow where [packages are installed on build](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages).  We [host a NuGet feed of our own](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/hosting-your-own-nuget-feeds#Creating_Remote_Feeds). We currently instruct developers to add this feed to their Visual Studio installation in the [package sources dialog](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/managing-nuget-packages-using-the-dialog#Package_Sources). This is tiresome. How can we share our feed so that anyone who checks out the code can get the packages?

I tried copying the `<packageSources>` element from `%appdata%\nuget\nuget.config` to `.nuget\nuget.config` (this is where Visual Studio saves 'package sources') but Visual Studio threw a hissy fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frustratingly, NuGet pays little attention to `.nuget\nuget.config`, ignoring any `<packageSources>` element. The solution to my problem was to edit `.nuget\NuGet.targets` and add the feed URLs to *its* `<packageSources>` element. Spuriously, this element has a different syntax—don't use `<add key` but instead put the feed URLs in quotes, separated by semi-colons.

```
<PackageSources>"http://melbourne.local/NuGetServer/nuget";"http://nuget.bizness.local"</PackageSources>
```

This issue on the NuGet bug tracker

- http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1861
- http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/286864